# Android GET Request

Tags: android, json, get, httpurlconnection, google-oauth

So I am trying to get back a JSON response that has an access token to use for my future requests to that API. However, when I send my request, it gives me a 200 response but that it failed.

Here is the bit of code that I believe is failing. I am not sure how long the `String token = bundle.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);` it lasts but I have had apps that don't request authentication again.

```
public class RetrieveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        private Exception exception;

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            responseView.setText("");
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            // Do some validation here

            try {
                URL url = new URL(API_URL + authPreferences.getToken());
                Log.i("URL", url.toString());
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
                System.out.println("GET Response code:" + responseCode);
                //urlConnection.addRequestProperty("client_id", ClientId);
//                urlConnection.addRequestProperty("client_secret", ClientSecret);
//                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "JWT " + authPreferences);

                try {
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;
                    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
                    }
                    bufferedReader.close();
                    return stringBuilder.toString();
                } finally {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage(), e);
                return null;
            }
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
            if (response == null) {
                response = "THERE WAS AN ERROR";
            }
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Log.i("INFO", response);
            responseView.setText(response);
            //
            // TODO: check this.exception
            // TODO: do something with the feed

//            try {
//                JSONObject object = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(response).nextValue();
//                String requestID = object.getString("requestId");
//                int likelihood = object.getInt("likelihood");
//                JSONArray photos = object.getJSONArray("photos");
//                .
//                .
//                .
//                .
//            } catch (JSONException e) {
//                e.printStackTrace();
//            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I wouldn't bother writing your own code for a HTTP connection.

Use OKHttp.

http://square.github.io/okhttp/

Here is some good recipes:

https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes

Somemore tutorial:

https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-OkHttp

OKHttp will handle authentication for you the way you set it up, and will auto renew when it fails to authenticate for you.

OKHttp will make your life easy. That being said, I do think that learning how to do this all with yourself is important and good, but someone else built the wheel for you already, and it works amazing.

Comment: So what's funny is OAuth 2.0 Playground gets the information I need. I just don't know what they use that I'm not using...